# Woocommerce function to hide product ID from user ID

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

I installed woocommerce on a site with a specific number of users who will be able to access the password protected store.

Q: is it possible to hide a product from all users EXCEPT for a few customers. I would like to create a function that would be...

> hide product ID (from all) except for user ID: 93, 64, 22 etc.

I need help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $user = get_current_user_id();
 if($user == '93' && get_post_meta(get the meta value of the product which applies to password protexted)) {
      show product here

 } else {
    dont_show
 }
```

You can hook this to pre_get_posts hook

Comment: Thanks, Dimitar, I’ll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the answer provided here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165691/how-to-check-if-a-user-exists-by-a-given-id

```
function user_id_exists($user){

    global $wpdb;

    $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users WHERE ID = %d", $user));

    if($count == 1){ return true; }else{ return false; }

}
```

I'd try with this: you'll need to use it in the `content-product.php` that you pulled in your `woocommerce` folder and edit the part with li to look like:

```
$user_id = 1

if(user_id_exists($user_id )){ 
    <li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

            /**
             * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
        ?>

    </a>

    <?php

        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

    ?>

</li>
} else {
    return;
}
```

You can create array of users and filter throught it with foreach loop and then in it make the if condition to see for each user.

Comment: Thanks, dingo_d , I’ll give it a try.